# Is "stuffed" correct and natural here?

Tags: word-choice

Is "stuffed" correct and natural here?

The shed was so stuffed with things that you could barely enter it.

Comment: It's possible, though we would be more likely to describe a container as 'stuffed with things' than a room or shed. 'Crammed' is more likely.

Comment: @KateBunting you might as well make your comment an answer

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with describing a shed as *stuffed with things,* though we would more often use that to describe a bag or other container. The shed could be *crammed* or *packed.*